# WhatsApp low quality voice call on high speed LTE modem

Tags: modem, voip, whatsapp

I've this TD-LTE modem with internet connection speed of around 20Mb/s. With this connection, everything works fine except the WhatsApp voice calls. What could be the reason for delayed voice and frequent loss of data? When on the same device I switch to another internet connection, the voice quality becomes excellent so I'm sure that the problem should be with the LTE modem. I read somewhere that this could be due to bad UDP settings. How can I find the root of the problem?

Answer (score 1):

WhatsApp must have the following ports open on your firewall:

```
TCP: 4244,5222,5223,5228,5242
TCP/UDP: 59234, 50318
UDP: 3478,45395
```

Once WhatsApp isn't blocked on these ports you should have better call quality. Some 4G data providers don't allow voice with third party programs like WhatsApp.

Comment: You mean the firewall on the provider side or a local firewall? Should all those ports be open? How can I check if they are not blocked?

Comment: You haven't stated what you are running whatsapp on, but I would first check the 4g account for any restrictions - You will probably have to speak to an advisor of theirs. Check the device whatsapp is on for a firewall, but it's not advisable or easy to have firewall instructions over superuser as it will require some knowledge of them.

Comment: There are plenty of programs/apps available to check a firewall - Just search!